# How to resize and remove the gap between arrow heads?

Tags: tikz-arrows

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
        \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=angle 90 ]
\draw[|<->|]            (0,0) -- (3,  0) node[right] {1};
\draw[{Bar[]<->Bar[]}]  (0,-1) -- (3,-1) node[right] {2};
\draw[{Bar[]Straight Barb[]-Straight Barb[]Bar[]}]   
                        (0,-2) -- (3,-2) node[right] {3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

[image]

**Questions**:

1. why all arrow head are not equal?
2. how to re-size Bar[], that its length and width will be doubled?

In TikZ manual (pp 201) is stated (in description for Barbed arrows tips):
"All of these arrow tips can be configured and resized in many different ways as described in the following.", but put a length or with for Bar gives an error,

Comment: which arrow head is not equal? They seem to be all the same size to me. For the length and width options, you are missing some brackets, I think it should be `{Bar[]<}-{>Bar[]}` and `{Bar[]Straight Barb[]}-{Straight Barb[]Bar[]}`

Comment: dcmst, the size are equal, but the position differ. The line 2 and 3 are equal (expected) but he arrow is for line width separated form Bar, what is not a case at line 1. In the case, that the Bar in line 2 or 3 can be resized, I like to have arrow till to bar. Additional curly brackets, as you suggested, doesnt change anything.

Comment: I see what you mean now. For the missing brackets, I mean that `{Bar[width=1cm]<}-{>Bar[]}` works, while `{Bar[width=1cm]<->Bar[]}` does not (this is for your second question).

Comment: sorry, before I overlook that behind of editor I had open in Adobe Reader XI a pdf image, which prevent to update image in Sumatra (which I normally use) ... After resetting of PC the image is as you describe. Thank you to solve my problem!

Comment: no problem. I edited the title so that (hopefully) the question will be helpful to more future readers. Feel free to rollback my edit if you disagree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get rid of the gap between arrows cap use a `.` between them:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
        \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=angle 90 ]
\draw[|<->|]            (0,0) -- (3,  0) node[right] {1};
\draw[{Bar[].<}-{>.Bar[]}]  (0,-.2) -- (3,-.2) node[right] {2};
\draw[{Bar[].Straight Barb[]}-{Straight Barb[].Bar[]}]   
                        (0,-.4) -- (3,-.4) node[right] {3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

[image]

To increase the width of `Bar` use `{Bar[width=<your value>].<}-{>.Bar[]}`